# Measure-theoretic force

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, field-theory, continuum-mechanics

I understand classical mechanics as a science of moving masses. So I decided to work out it formulation based on measure there just for fun.  In this framework the classical mechanical system would be represented as a tuple $(X,\mu_t)$, where $X$ is possibly an infinite-dimensional affine space, and $\mu_t$ is a moving finite measure changing with time $t \in \mathbb{R}$, representing mass. The mass conservation can be formulated then as an  existence of smooth (in $t$) transport mapping $T_t$ such that $\mu_t = T_{t\#}(\mu_0)$ is a pushfoward. That is, $T_{t\#}(\mu_0)(A) = \mu_0(T^{-1}_t A)$ for a set $A \subset X$. In this formulation the finite set of $n$ material points $x_i$ with masses $m_i$ can be written as $\mu = \sum^n_{i=1} m_i\delta_{x_i}$, where $\delta_x$ is a delta-measure concentrated at a point $x$. The continuum mechanics must also be implementable with different moving measures $\mu$.

Then, there is a straightforward derivation of displacement $\vec D_t = T_t -  \mathrm{id}$, velocity $\vec V_t = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} T_t$ and acceleration $\vec A_t = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} T_t$ fields. It's also possible to compute a momentum $\vec p = \int_X \vec V\mathrm{d}\mu$ and integral force $\vec f = \int_X \vec A\mathrm{d}\mu$ vectors of the system. The problem is that these vector-values are too global, and so, not very useful. Ideally, I want be able to produce a "force field" $\frac{\vec F_t}{\mathrm{d}\mu}(x)$  from initial datum $(\vec D,\mu_0)$ at every point $x$ that has any mas at moment of time $t$. This should be more useful, as than it must be possible to decompose $\frac{\vec F}{\mathrm{d}\mu}= \left(\frac{\vec F}{\mathrm{d}\mu}\right)_{\mathrm{external}} + \vec G_\mu$, where

$$
  \vec G_\mu(x) = G\int_X \frac{(y - x)}{\| y - x\|^3} \mathrm{d}\mu(y),
$$

is a gravitational  field due to mass $\mu$ and $G$ is a gravitational constant. In case of a point-particle $x$ with mass $m$, this becomes $\vec F(x) = m\vec A(x)$. So, is it always possible to assume that $\frac{\vec F}{\mathrm{d}\mu} = \vec A$ at the support of $\mu$?

However, it seems that in more general (or continuum) cases the concept of force at the point do not make any sense, because points don't have mass anymore. Then, the only item left is the "force element" $\mathrm{d} \vec F = \vec A \mathrm{d} \mu$. I don't have any experience in continuum mechanics, so, is anything like this notion of "force element" is actually used?

Comment: I think you want the [stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor)?

Comment: @jacob1729, thanks. I think that it would be really nice to build a pathway from this "force element" to the stress tensor. It seems that the key problem here is relating it with the stress vector. Something like $ \lim_{|S| \to 0} \frac{\int_S \mathrm{d} F}{|S|}  $

Comment: If you want fields then you need to develop a field theory. Perhaps you should then consider measures on manifolds and their (co)tangent bundles.

Comment: @Phoenix87  you are right. Use of Affine space in here is a simplification.